# How to name a check in Gatling response

Tags: gatling

My expectation is that if 'title' is `<title>An error has occurred</title>` instead of
`<title>Member Home</title>` in the response,
I should get error message like

```
"Expected page :: Member Home", but actually found An error has occurred.
```

Instead i am getting this message

```
css((title,None)).find.is(Member Home), but actually found An error has occurred
```

How can i replace `css((title,None)).find.is(Member Home)` with custom error message

Below is the check i am using

```
check(
 status is 200,
 css("title") name "Expected page :: Member Home",
 css("title") is "Member Home"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
check(
 status is 200,
 css("title").name("Expected page :: Member Home").is("Member Home")
)
```

Comment: Found the solution

`css("title").is("Member Home").name("Expected page :: Member Home")`

Thanks, @Stephane